# docker compose down doesn't shutdown / remove container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having a simple problem with `docker compose down` that I've already researched, but can't find a solution for. Any guidance is appreciated.

`docker compose up` works fine, but when I try to down the project, one container won't shutdown / remove. This causes an `error while removing network: ... has active endpoints` error during docker compose down.

Here's how I start the containers:
`yarn docker:compose:test:up`, which runs `"docker compose -f docker-compose.test.yml up"`. Everything starts fine, and life goes on.

Here's the entire `docker-compose.test.yml` file:

```
---
services:
  redis:
    networks:
      - redis-network
    command:
      - redis-server
      - "--appendonly"
      - "yes"
      - "--requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}"
    image: redis
    container_name: resonate-redis
    restart: always

    expose:
      - 6379
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"

  api:
    networks:
      - api-network
      - redis-network
    build: .
    command: /bin/sh -c "yarn && yarn migrate:test && yarn start:dev"
    container_name: resonate-api
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - pgsql-test
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/api
      - ./data/media/incoming:/data/media/incoming
      - ./data/media/audio:/data/media/audio
      - ./data/media/images:/data/media/images

  pgsql-test:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./data/pgsql-test:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./data/pgsql-test-backups:/backups
    container_name: resonate-pgsql-test
    networks:
      - api-network
    ports:
      - '${POSTGRES_TEST_LOCAL_MACHINE_PORT}:5432'
  nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: resonate-nginx
    networks:
      - api-network
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "${NGINX_PORT}:80"

networks:
  api-network:
    driver: bridge
  # app-network:
  #   driver: bridge
  redis-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  certbot-var:
  htpasswd:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "${PWD}/htpasswd/"
      o: bind
  web-root:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "${PWD}/public/"
      o: bind
  dhparam:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: "${PWD}/dhparam/"
      o: bind

version: "3.7"
```

Later, I run `docker compose down` and end up with this output:

```
(base) iMac:api imac$ docker compose down
[+] Running 4/5
 ⠿ Container resonate-nginx   Removed                  0.3s
 ⠿ Container resonate-api     Removed                  0.5s
 ⠿ Container resonate-redis   Removed                  0.3s
 ⠿ Network api_redis-network  Removed                  0.1s
 ⠿ Network api_api-network    Error                    0.0s
failed to remove network api_api-network: Error response from daemon: error while removing network: network api_api-network id ... has active endpoints
```

The `pgsql-test` container is not removed, and the network can't stop because of this.

I have no idea why this is happening, or what to do in order to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does using the same `-f` option help, `docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml down`?  Do you have a plain `docker-compose.yml` file with similar content?

Comment: yes, that solved the problem.

and yes there is also `a plain docker-compose.yml file with similar content`.

something simple and obvious, that it just didn't occur to me.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Just had this happen to me.

> failed to remove network ots_djangoapp: Error response from daemon:
> error while removing network: network ots_djangoapp id 1450efd2df6c
> has active endpoints

Had been working for years, but it looks as though one of the updates changed things. Possibly in the 2.7.0 bug fixes https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

My yml config utilized profiles

https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/

Which I would start with `docker-compose --profile prod up -d` and `docker-compose down` respectively.

I got it working again by simply adding the explicit --profile argument to the down command.

`docker-compose --profile prod down`

-cheers